# Quotient Spaces and Shapes

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Consider the unit interval
$[0,1]$. If I glue the end points together through the usual equivalence relation:

for $x,y\in [0,1]$, $x\sim y$ $\iff$ $x=y$ or $\{$ $x,y$ $\}$ $=$ $\{$ 0,1 $\}$.

Then the quotient space $[0,1]\backslash \sim$ is the $"same"$ as the unit circle in the plane. Because end points are mapped to endpoints, does that informally imply that the unit circle is homeomorphic to a triangle, a square, a rectangle and etc?

Comment: What exactly **is** a triangle purely in topological terms?

Comment: Heuristically and informally, I mean.

Comment: If certain mathematical objects cannot be discerned in the theory of topology then automatically they are the same in the theory of topology. External differences are "modded out".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometric shape is not a topological property. In fact, a circle, a triangle, a square etc. are homeomorphic spaces. You can write down explicit homeomorphisms if you want.

It does not make sense to associate a *specific* shape of a plane object to $[0,1]/\sim$.

The choice is completely arbitrary.